# How to add Header on the report

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I'm trying to create report that looks something like this: But my question is what how would i go ahead and create this type of report?

From `Employee Name..to..End Date` can go in header of the report? if thats the case then how can I add those fields in the header of the report?

```
Employee Name: XXXXXXXXX     Merchant Id: XXXXXXXXXXX
Manager Name:  XXXXXXXXX     Camp Name  : XXXXXXXXXXX     End Date: MM/DD/YYYY

Serial Number     Account Name        Account Manager
XXXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXX        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  
XXXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXX        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXX        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXX        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXXXX        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Do I need to work with Visualforce page? in order to have the above format on the report?

Comment: I have gotten frequent requests for things similiar to this and I have always had to make a custom Visualforce page. Should be an easy Visualforce Page to create.

Comment: another alternative is to use Conga Composer and its ilk (like DrawLoop).  You use Excel as the report template and Conga merges in SFDC reports and query results into your template. Hence you get almost unlimited presentation abilities.

Comment: or Apsona - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003JejzEAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a Visualforce page for this. That is how I have approached this problem.

Here's an example brutually simple Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Header Parent Object">
        <apex:outputPanel layout="Block" style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <apex:outputText value="{!Account.Name}"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Child Object">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="cont">
        <apex:column value="{!cont.FirstName}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!cont.LastName}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!cont.CreatedDate}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

The output:

[image]

There is more than one way to display this using visualforce, this is just an example.

Comment: Please add a little more detail on your solution if possible.

Comment: @Mercury86: can you share the visualforce page if possible

Comment: @NickKahn coming right up! Let me dig an example out of one of my dev boxes real quick.

Comment: @NickKahn Added to my answer.

Comment: I see it's simple vfp but how are you printing this report I'm assuming you work on how the output will looks like when the user click on print?

Comment: @NickKahn I havent had any issues with users using the "Printable View" option on the detail page. The width is in percent, lengths in pixels (might have to tweak it), really comes down to how many reports you expect this to return.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking you too many details but I'm not sure if I understand your last reply, what I meant by that, did you write the code for printing the report (printable veiw)?

Comment: @NickKahn No worries Nick. I havent had any need to write code for printing. If you place this Visualforce page on the object detail page you can make use of the standard "Printable View" functionality. How many records are you expecting to be returned? Adjust the height in pixels to accomdate that.

Comment: okay I see and I was not aware of the printable view option but mine is little bit completed, i'm talking about couple of thousands rows - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking on the Printing View from the report - the button is a bit little mislead, however, you will prompt you to download a version of the report which has a nice header with your report filters at the top.

Comment: Yes but it will not have the format I want